# Use different assets for debug and release

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I would like to use different database files for debug and release builds. Is it possible to do it with using gradle and two different directories like *assets* and *assets_deb* for instance?

The verification code in the app, like this `android.os.Debug.isDebuggerConnected()` is not suitable in my situation.

Thanks

Comment: Best is to use BuildConfig.DEBUG check. If true, use file for debug builds and so.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use **different** assets folder, like:

```
app/src/main/assets
app/src/debug/assets
app/src/release/assets
```

Or you can define different src folders in the `build.gradle` file:

```
sourceSets {

        main.java.srcDirs = ['...']
        main.res.srcDirs = ['...']
        main.assets.srcDirs = ['...']
        debug.assets.srcDirs = ['...']
        flavor1.assets.srcDirs = ['...']
    }
```

To check the "debug" value you can use the default `BuildConfig.DEBUG`.
In the same way you can define your own boolean value:

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField "boolean", "MYVALUE", "true"
        }
        release {
            buildConfigField "boolean", "MYVALUE", "false"
        }
    }
```

The automatically-generated `BuildConfig class` will contain the following fields based on the directive above:

```
public class BuildConfig {
    // ... other generated fields ...
    public static final boolean MYVALUE = false;
}
```

Comment: It would be worthwhile to note about how the files are processed from these directories as resources do not need to be duplicated. there is priority processing logic in gradle to handle all this...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. Just create another folder in your `src` folder as below:

-- src
----- debug
--------- assets
----- main
--------- assets

If you need something like different application name in Debug mode, you can define new `res/value` folder in `debug` folder as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try build variant check below example

http://blog.brainattica.com/how-to-work-with-flavours-on-android/

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html